# How can I modify style options in MapViewer to only display records that are less than 1 year old?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, arcade

**What I have:**

- A hosted joined view layer with a Inspection Date field ('insdate') and an Operable field ('h_operable'). The view is defined such that it only holds the most recent record for each asset. I.e. Assetid 1 will have a single Inspection Date and operable value. The table currently has several records with inspection dates shown below:

[image]

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

- If Inspection date is less than 1 year old and Operable is equal to 1 then symbology class would be "Operable".
- If Inspection date is less than 1 year old and Operable is equal to 2 then symbology class would be "Inoperable"
- If inspection date is more than 1 year old then symbology class would be null or other and not displayed.

**What I have tried:**
The following code is what I have attempted to use in the Style Options expression in MapViewer

```
var now = Date();
var inspection = $feature["insdate_1682094024219"];
var age = DateDiff(inspection, now);
var op =$feature["h_operable"];
var opcondition = age < 365 && op == 1;
var inopcondition =  age < 365 && op == 0;
var nodraw = age > 365
When(opcondition, "Operable", inopcondition, "Inoperable", nodraw, "Other", "Inconclusive");
```

**Issue:**

- Whenever I apply, the `op == x` value is honored, and drawn as defined in `var opcondition` or `var inopcondition`. However, the date parameter is NOT honored, and records that are more than 365 days old still draw as `"Operable"` or `"Inoperable"` instead of `"Other"`. This is pictured below, where the date is more than 1 year old, and still being drawn on the map.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to split this between a filter for the date, and a separate expression for the Operable function?

The only reason I bring this up is, it sounds like you are trying to filter out everything more than a year old anyway. Map viewer filters for this have worked for me, and then all you're adding is the operability expression by itself.

Comment: It looks like this will be the route I end up taking on this project. I will update once I am able to get back around and attempt to implement this.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Honestly, I am not sure how I was overlooking filters when I was writing this question. Thank you!

Comment: You're kindly welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To comment on why the Arcade script might not have had the results you expected:

- Datediff subtracts the second date from the first. If `inspection` occurs before `now`, the result will be negative unless you swap the arguments.
- The default unit of `datediff` is milliseconds, not days. You can specify a third parameter for units, including `'years'`.
- https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/date_functions/#datediff

So when you ran the script `age` was likely a large negative number representing the milliseconds difference between the two datetimes. This modified script may be closer to your initial description.

```
var now = Date();
var inspection = $feature["insdate_1682094024219"];
var age = DateDiff(now, inspection, 'years');
var op = $feature["h_operable"];
var opcondition = age < 1 && op == 1;
var inopcondition =  age < 1 && op == 0;
var nodraw = age > 1
When(opcondition, "Operable", inopcondition, "Inoperable", nodraw, "Other", "Inconclusive");
```

Filters are likely to be more performant that the corresponding Arcade script.

Comment: Thanks for the input! My arcade is still very beginner level. Alex Page above you definitely had the simpler solution. I'm not sure why I was completely looking over filters when I wrote this question.